# The nextLine method is giving me an incorrect implementation

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

Why `nextLine()` method doesn't work? I mean, I can not enter any sentence after the second scan call because the program runs to the end and exits.

Input: `era era food food correct correct sss sss exit`

Should I use another `Scanner` object?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Today{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str="";
    String exit="exit";

    System.out.println("Please enter some words : ");
    while(true){

    str=scan.next();
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(exit)) break;
    System.out.println(str);

    }

    System.out.println("Please enter a sentnce : ");
    String sentence1 = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("the word you entered is : " + sentence1);
}

}
```

Comment: What does _`doesn't work`_ mean specifically?

Comment: I can not enter any sentence after the second scan call

Comment: Please, post the input data you're using.

Comment: Please enter some words : 
era
era
food
food
correct
correct
sss
sss
exit
Please enter a sentence : 
the word you entered is :

Comment: After `Please enter a sentence :` was printed what (sentence) did you (actually) enter?

Comment: I can't enter anything , Imagine the code without this line -> String sentence1 = scan.nextLine();
and sorry for my awful english!

Comment: It doesn't allow to enter any sentence

Comment: I fixed it by defining another Scanner object,Thanks for your help and try

Comment: I don't think you need another scanner

Comment: I have no any other idea right now,but I will search for another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What [`Scanner#nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) does is to

> Advance this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end.

Since your input is `era era food food correct correct sss sss exit` you read inside the `while` every word with `Scanner#next`, so when `Scanner#nextLine` is called it returns `""` (empty string) because there is nothing left of that line. That's why you see `the word you entered is :` (at the begging of the text is the empty string).

If you would have used this input: `era era food food correct correct sss sss exit lastWord` you would have seen `the word you entered is :  lastWord`

The only thing you need to do in order **to fix** this is to call `scan.nextLine();` first to move to the next line for the new input the user is going to provide and then get the new word with `Scanner#nextLine()` like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String str="";
String exit="exit";

System.out.println("Please enter some words : ");
while(true){
    str=scan.next();
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(exit)) break;
    System.out.println(str);
}

scan.nextLine(); // consume rest of the string after exit word
System.out.println("Please enter a sentnce : ");
String sentence1 = scan.nextLine(); // get sentence

System.out.println("the word you entered is : " + sentence1);
```

**Demo**: https://ideone.com/GbwBds

Comment: Yes Exactly,Thank you,It works and it is also a better idea